# Given $(a,4)=2, (b,4)=2$, prove $(a+b,4)=4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

So if $(a,4)=2,$ then $a=4k+2$, for some integer $k$

if $(b,4)=2$, then $b=4m+2$, for some integer $m$

Then $a+b=4(k+m)+4=4(k+m+1)$  So $a+b$ is a multiple of $4$, and thus, $(a+b,4)=4$.

Are my first two statements obvious or do I have to prove those as well?  I'd like to think they are obvious, but assuming obviousness seems like a bad way to do proofs.

Comment: Also m and k have to be odd

Comment: Why do $m$ and $k$ have to be odd?  Won't $a\equiv 2\mod 4$ regardless of $m$ and $k$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the hypothesis we have $a=2a'$ and $b=2b'$ where $a'$ and $b'$ are odd numbers so $a+b=2(a'+b')$ and $a'+b'$ is even say equal $2c$ and the result is now clear.

Comment: This seems like a better way abou the problem than mine.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Sweet!${}{}{}{}{}$